# ZeroMQ, how to properly read message ignoring envelope?

Tags: php, zeromq

I'm using this ZeroMQ pattern:

[image]

that I believe is named [Shared Queue (DEALER and ROUTER sockets)](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Shared-Queue-DEALER-and-ROUTER-sockets)

I have made some little changes to the examples contained in the ZGuide:

- the client after sending `REQ` does not wait for the reply
- the broker reads the worker reply and it handles it internally (without sanding it back to the client)

This works fine, the only problem is that when the broker prints worker's reply, the message is always precede by

```
k�E}
 # (an empty string)
```

I think that this is due to ZeroMQ message envelope, but what would be the proper way to get handle that so to get only the **real message**?

## client.php

```
<?php
$context = new ZMQContext();

//  Socket to talk to server
$requester = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ);
$requester->connect("tcp://localhost:5559");

$msg = "Ciao ".strrev(uniqid());

echo "→ $msg\n";
$requester->send($msg);
```

## broker.php

```
<?php
//  Prepare our context and sockets
$context = new ZMQContext();
$frontend = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_ROUTER);
$backend = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_DEALER);
$frontend->bind("tcp://*:5559");
$backend->bind("tcp://*:5560");

//  Initialize poll set
$poll = new ZMQPoll();
$poll->add($frontend, ZMQ::POLL_IN);
$poll->add($backend, ZMQ::POLL_IN);
$readable = $writeable = array();

//  Switch messages between sockets
while (true) {
    $events = $poll->poll($readable, $writeable);

    foreach ($readable as $socket) {
        if ($socket === $frontend) {
            //  Process all parts of the message
            while (true) {
                $message = $socket->recv();
                //  Multipart detection
                $more = $socket->getSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_RCVMORE);
                $backend->send($message, $more ? ZMQ::MODE_SNDMORE : null);
                if (!$more) {
                    break; //  Last message part
                }
            }
        } elseif ($socket === $backend) {
            $message = $socket->recv();
            echo "← $message\n";
        }
    }
}
```

## worker.php

```
<?php
$context = new ZMQContext();

//  Socket to talk to clients
$responder = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_REP);
$responder->connect("tcp://localhost:5560");

while (true) {
    //  Wait for next request from client
    $string = $responder->recv();
    printf ("Received request: [%s]%s", $string, PHP_EOL);

    // Do some 'work'
    sleep(1);

    //  Send reply back to client
    $responder->send("Hi $string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the PHP 0MQ API, but it looks like you want to use [recvMulti](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zmqsocket.recvmulti.php) instead of `recv`.  `recvMulti` returns each message frame in an array.  In your case you could then skip element 0 and get your "real" message from element 1.